# How to pass GPS (lat,lon etc) to Android services

Tags: service, gps, listener

I'm trying to build a background service which is able to log the data and save it into a SQLite database at a specific time interval without user consent.

So far:

1. I was able to start the services and toast current LastKnownLocation. This just to see if the variable is okay before I insert it to SQLite table.
2. However, if the GPS is not active the application will crash.

What's wrong with my code, and how to make it auto change when location changes?

```
public class SpycareServices extends Service {

/*Location Listener Declaration*/
PhoneInfo myPhone;
Util myFunction;
private LocationListener listener;
private LocationManager locationManager;
boolean gps_enabled = false;
boolean network_enabled = false;
Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null, finalLoc = null;
public double longitude,latitude;


/*Declare SharedPref StartService*/

public SpycareServices(){

}

/*Declare constructor for location listener*/
public SpycareServices(Context context){
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(){


    /*Instantiate listener*/
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Check which provider active
    gps_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    network_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if(gps_enabled)
    {
        gps_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    if(network_enabled)
    {
        net_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        //net_loc = locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,3000,0,listener);
    }

    /*If both gps and network has value, choose the better one*/
    if (gps_loc != null && net_loc != null) {

        //smaller the number more accurate result will
        if (gps_loc.getAccuracy() > net_loc.getAccuracy()){
            finalLoc = net_loc;
            //
        }
        else{
            finalLoc = gps_loc;
            //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,0,listener);
        }
    } else {
        if (gps_loc != null) {
            finalLoc = gps_loc;
        } else if (net_loc != null) {
            finalLoc = net_loc;
        }
    }

}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Services Has Been Started!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Instance util to get timestamp
    myFunction = new Util(this);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"My time "+ myFunction.getTimestamp(this),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //Instance Imei
    myPhone = new PhoneInfo(this);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"My Imei "+ myPhone.betaGetImei(this),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"My Location Provider is "+ finalLoc.getProvider(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"My Longitude is "+ finalLoc.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"My Latitude is "+ finalLoc.getLatitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Services Has Been Destroyed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //super.onDestroy();

    //Prevent memory leaks by deregister listener when destroyed
    if(locationManager!=null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not be surprised if nobody is keen to spend their spare time helping you spy on people.

Comment: Its for my Final Project, software for parent to track thier child mobile activity. "We spy because we care"..T.T